# Check if IP is static or dynamic programmatically in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp

I'm trying to determine whether my IP has been statically or dynamically assigned in Ubuntu 11.04 from within C. The closest I've come is examining `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases`, but that doesn't change if a static IP is assigned (as it caches DHCP leases for future connection attempts).

So... is there a command line utility (for Ubuntu) that will allow me to check if DHCP is enabled or disabled?

Alternatively: the machine is a server dedicated to one application; would it be easier just to maintain an environment variable that keeps track of DHCP status?

Answer (score 1):

In theory if you dhcp is enabled, you should have dhclient running. So one (albeit kludgey) way to do it would be simply:

ps ax | grep dhclient | grep eth0 (or whichever interface you want).

But you may also want to try "nmcli con" which will tell you "Auto eth0" (I think) if it's a dhcp interface.

Also take a look at nm-tool

HTH

Comment: Note: You may also examine `/var/run/dhclient.eth0.pid` (or whichever interface you want...)

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible through NetworkManager's DBUS API but source of IP address doesn't pop out in the list of interfaces, try discussing with the developers of said application.

http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/developers/spec.html